# Do edits made very close together in time always show up as separate edits in the edit history?

Tags: support

Do edits made very close together in time always show up as separate edits in the edit history?

I guess I thought that when I was seeing an autofill suggestion in the "Edit Summary" box that was the same as I typed in there during a previous like 30 seconds before, it might show up as the same edit.

Still trying to better understand how this all works--

Added content: for example just after posting this question I made two quick edits to this question, each with the title "syntax" in the "Edit Summary" box, and I'm not seeing them in the edit history for this question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214892/392799):

> Edits made by the same editor in a short period of time are collapsed: no matter how many times a post is edited within a 5-minute window, only one revision is stored (as long as only one editor is involved). This largely eliminates the need for a "minor edit" feature [used by Wikipedia].